# in R - repeatation of numbers in two column - unable to get the exact result

Tags: r

I wanted to repeat certain numbers and I am using the following code.

```
list1 <- 7101:7118
list2 <- rep(c(1,2,3,4,21,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,45,46,47,48), length(list1))
list3 <- cbind(list1, list2)
```

Unfortunately, I am not getting the result like the following what I want:

```
7101    1
7101    2
7101    3
7101    4
7101    21
7101    22
7101    23
7101    24
7101    25
7101    26
7101    27
7101    28
7101    45
7101    46
7101    47
7101    48
7102    1
7102    2
7102    3
7102    4
7102    21
7102    22
7102    23
7102    24
7102    25
7102    26
7102    27
7102    28
7102    45
7102    46
7102    47
7102    48
7103    1
7103    2
7103    3
7103    4
```

please let me know where I did wrong and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `each`

```
list2 <- rep(c(1,2,3,4,21,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,45,46,47,48), each=length(list1))
```